# best way to make BPMN graph for a ERP system

Tags: business-process-management, 3-tier

We have an ERP system made in java that we will adapt to 3-tier architecture, and we want to add transaction controls (JTA).

We read that the best way to analyze where to place the controls was to create a graph of the system scenarios using BPM and then adding controls to the graph.

the web give us 2 ways to make the graph:

1. By way of use (scenarios) of each module, adding to the graph the
   different routes that can be done by using a module, for example: in
   the invoice module the different ways to complete it (with detail,
   without detail, etc...)
2. By relation between the modules, adding to the graph how passes from
   module to module, for example in invoice how passes to client
   account

Our question are:

1. Which is the best way?
2. Is there another way to do that?

Comment: You are mixing things a bit here.

JTA is a low-level API implemented by Java JDBC drivers or Spring to help developers write code that will work with transactions - did you mean that you would like to implement a BPM transactional system orchestrating services around a transaction ? If you would like to implement a BPM method, you should probably indeed go top-down starting from the value chain, then to high level processes and keep digging until you get the right level of detail.

Answer (score -1):

Definitely, using a BPM solution like jBPM will help you to define your business scenarios and discover the interaction between the different departments and modules in your company. If you want to use BPM there will be some things to learn, I would suggest you to take a look at BPM solutions and see if that can help you in your specific implementation.